# Spring MVC: @RequestParam not seen with POST

Tags: http, spring-mvc, post

Given:
Spring MVC
Controller method mapped to POST
Body parameters "abc=1&def=2"
However, the method 'reads' correctly the parameters only if they are given in the URL, not in the body. (The requests are done with a browser tool that makes POST requests)
Why?

`@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public  @ResponseBody String something( @RequestParam(value="abc", required=false) String abc,  @RequestParam(value="def", required=false) String def)....`

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` header set for your POST request ? I think that should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for this to work.